# Open Graph tags rendering but not working on facebook debug

Tags: html, next.js, seo

I'm using Next.js + SSG to render my pages, here's what my `<Head />` looks like:

```html
<Head>
  <title>{title}</title>
  <meta name="title" content={`${title} - MySite`} />
  <meta name="description" content={description} />

  <meta name="og:title" content={title} />
  <meta name="og:description" content={description} />
  <meta
    name="og:image"
    content={`${getBaseUrl()}/static/images/logo.png`}
  />
  <meta
    name="og:image:secure_url"
    content={`${getBaseUrl()}/static/images/logo.png`}
  />
  <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="1920" />
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="1080" />
  <meta property="og:image:alt" content="mysite logo image" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="mysite" />
  <meta property="og:url" content={getBaseUrl()} />
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
</Head>
```

The rendered HTML looks like this:

```html
<title>Home</title>
<meta name="title" content="Home - MySite" />
<meta name="description" content="MySite desc" />

<meta name="og:title" content="Home" />
<meta name="og:description" content="MySite desc" />
<meta
  name="og:image"
  content="https://mysite.so/static/images/logo.png"
/>
<meta
  name="og:image:secure_url"
  content="https://mysite.so/static/images/logo.png"
/>
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1920" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="1080" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="mysite logo image" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="mysite" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://mysite.so" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
```

But nothing seems to work... Facebook Debug doesn't pick up anything. It says: `The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.`

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Live site can be seen here: https://dev.reactive.so

Comment: Do the metatags also appear in the page source? The live site URL doesn't work, btw.

Comment: I fixed the issue thanks, I'll post an answer here in a sec. Yeah Namecheap blocked my account for 'suspicious' activities lol...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was due to the package `next-themes` needing pages to be conditionally rendered to avoid a theme flicker. Here's a [link](https://github.com/herbievine/reactive.so/pull/3/commits/efea2eb2660144731eae6c0dda6d6815e5f6a43c) to the PR if you're interested.